# Chinese SIM cards

Tags: china, cellphones, price, data-plans

I'm planning to go to China next January. I'm wondering about what kind of SIM card I should buy for having a data internet connection in Shanghai and Nanjing. I also want know about the price of new a new connection and data packages.